# jsf-2.0 how to pass a value from one class to another 

Tags: jsf-2

I have one extended Data Table in *payeeSearch.xhtml* displayed as -[image]

1) After clicking on *show particulars*, it should navigate to a different view and display a new table based on the result achieved by one of the column's value of the selected row (In figure, it is *IN303285...*)
2) I have written code for navigating to the next view as -

```
<rich:contextMenu attached="false" id="menu" submitMode="ajax">
      <rich:menuItem ajaxSingle="true" value="Show Particulars" action="payeeParticulars.xhtml">
           <a4j:support event="onclick" actionListener="#{payeeSearchController.showParticulars}"/>
      </rich:menuItem>
```

3) This view (*payeeParticulars.xhtml*) is displaying another extendedDataTable.
And the *showPartulatrs* actionlistener is being used to pass the column's value of the selected row to *PayeeParticulars.java* class, But it is always passing the null value even though I am able to get the value in *payeeSearch.java* class.
4) I am writing code to display the new extendedDataTable in constructor of the *PayeeParticulars.java* class

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong, or how to pass the value of one column of the selected row to **another view** and display the result accordingly in a new extendedDataTable.

Please help me out....

Comment: how about placing a4j:commandbutton inside rich:menuItem ?

Comment: if you need conditional navigation , why dont you use action="" for conditional navigation ?

Comment: b.t.w look here , might find something http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/3.3.X/3.3.3.Final/en/tlddoc/a4j/support.html

Comment: I have already used conditional navigation as what u r telling and i got it working, but not with *rich:menuItem* and *a4j:commandbutton* inside that is not working

Comment: that a4j:support also i have used not working as expected,,

Comment: what is happening with *a4j:support* is it is executing after the *rich:menuItem* loaded for displaying the view as described in the above code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use rich:menuItem like this....

```
<rich:menuItem submitMode="ajax" value="Show Particulars" action="#{payeeParticularsController.showParticular}"/>
```

and then in controller file put

```
public String showParticular()
{
   // operation
   return "details";
}
```

and then in navigation rules set one rule as -

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/payeeSearch.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>details</from-outcome>
        <if>#{payeeParticularsController.selectedFolioNo != null}</if>
        <to-view-id>/payeeParticulars.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

It will let you pass the value from one class to another and also new view will not be loaded until the `if` condition will be satisfied.