# Conditional navigation in JSF2.0

Tags: jsf-2

Is it possible to do conditional navigation in JSF2.0 using navigation-rule in faces-config 2.0 ??
For Example -

```
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/payeeSearch.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>details</from-outcome>
        <if>#{payeeParticularsController.selectedFolioNo != null}</if>
        <to-view-id>/payeeParticulars.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is

take a look at this [Conditional Navigation Rule in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/conditional-navigation-rule-in-jsf-2-0/)

and this

[Fluent Navigation in JSF 2](http://java.dzone.com/articles/fluent-navigation-jsf-2)

and this

[Learning JSF2: Navigation](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/09/learning-jsf2-navigation/)

---

[google](https://www.google.com/search?q=conditional%20navigation%20in%20jsf2&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) is great isn't it ?

Comment: i tried it already and it is working for *a4j:commandbutton* but not working for *rich:menuItem* so that's why i asked..

Comment: than you should write your question better , I can't guess it... You asked about "Conditional navigation" you haven't mention any relevance to RichFaces nor a4j:commandbutton nor rich:menuItem.... B.T.W how about placing a4j:commandbutton inside rich:menuItem ?

Comment: I have already posted one other question but nobody replied so i tried something on my own and found out one solution. but different than what i expected...

Comment: Oki, If no one answered the other question maybe you should simplify it and make it more easy to understand....

Comment: (Here is the link to that original question....)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10492821/jsf-2-0-how-to-pass-a-value-from-one-class-to-another]

Comment: Sorry, have no experience with richfaces... but I posted a comment over there now...

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @BalusC, I did answered very briefly "Yes it is..." and gave several examples... whats wrong ?

Comment: I don't see any example suiting OP's case in your answer.

Comment: OP's had no case , it was a general question "Is it possible to do conditional navigation in JSF2.0 using navigation-rule in faces-config 2.0 " so I said Yes and gave several ref's to complete example , no point to copy paste entire web sites in this case...